# Is it possible to run docker image/DockerFile on AWS Lambda?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, aws-lambda, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, dockerfile

I want to deploy a docker image with my given Dockerfile that executes a program on the AWS Lambda cloud. I know it is possible for EC2 but I want to use AWS Lambda. Anyone have references or know if it is possible?

I was looking at the AWS Elastic Beanstalk as well that has docker capabilities, but it seems it is for web applications? My program that i'm trying to execute on the cloud is NOT a web application.

Comment: What's the point? Anyway, maybe [this link](https://hackernoon.com/how-did-i-hack-aws-lambda-to-run-docker-containers-7184dc47c09b) can help you

Comment: @juanlumn I'll take a look at that. What do you mean what's the point? Does it seem not practical? Please let me know.

Comment: I'm just curious about it

Comment: @juanlumn The reason was because the program i'm trying to deploy has a lot of dependencies and packages that are needed, also it uses ArchLinux. Therefore I was having issues using Amazon Lambda itself to run this program, that is why I went toward docker and wanted to deploy it on there first and then deploy the image on aws lambda.

Comment: Amazon has [an entire service for this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/Welcome.html).  Why Lambda?  That seems like a mismatch in what Lambda is meant to do vs. ECS.

Comment: @stdunbar Because with AWS Lambda, it's free and I get 1M free requests per month. ECS I get charged.

Comment: ECS is not at all what this question is seeking.  This question is asking about a serverless compute platform that allows you to provide your own containers.  Such a product in Google Cloud Platform, known as "Google Cloud Run".  I don't know if any equivalent exists in AWS.

Comment: ECS requires one or more instances running all the time. Lambda is serverless so you only pay for runtime in response to requests. A Docker image can encapsulate your entire application. Running Docker in Lambda seems like it might make deploying a large Lambda application simpler and easier.

Comment: It's not the same but you might want to check out https://aws.amazon.com/fargate/ which lets you run containers without the need of maintaining the underlying servers.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's an article covering this as well as two projects. Here's the [article](https://hackernoon.com/how-did-i-hack-aws-lambda-to-run-docker-containers-7184dc47c09b), and these two are frameworks for doing so.

- [docker-in-aws-lambda](https://github.com/vladgolubev/docker-in-aws-lambda) (from the article)
- [docker-lambda](https://github.com/lambci/docker-lambda)

Comment: the question was to run docker on lambda, not run lambda inside docker.

Comment: Just for clarity, the two projects mentioned are different things: "docker-in-aws-lambda" lets you run a shell script from a python/nodejs/etc. lambda, and from the shell script run a docker image.  That's what the OP asked for.  The "docker-lambda" link is something different, that just provides docker images that act like lambda environments.

Answer (score 12):

This has just been announced and it is now possible to run Docker inside of Lambda here is the link for the announcement:

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-for-aws-lambda-container-image-support/

[image: Lambda Container Example]